# Python - Execution time takes longer than usual

Tags: python, python-2.7

I decided to make a simple python code to easily get the day when date is entered in `m/d/yyyy` format. I uploaded the dates into a .txt file using excel. The new .txt file contains date starting `1/1/2018` to `12/31/2022` with corresponding day separated by a comma.

The program works fine but it takes almost a minute to get the result. How can I change the code to improve the execution time?

Here's my code:

```
def getList():
   name = 'Calendar2018.txt'
   dates = open(name, 'r')
   newList = []
   for line in dates:
       newList.append(line)
   for i in range(0,len(newList)):
       newList[i] = newList[i].split(',')
   for i in range (0,len(newList)):
       for x in range (0,len(newList[i])):
          newList[i][x] = (str(newList[i][x]).translate(None,'"')).strip()
   return newList

userInp = raw_input("Enter a date: ")
for i in range(0,len(getList())):
    if (getList()[i][0]) == userInp:
        print userInp + " falls on " + getList()[i][1] + "."
```

Comment: First, figure out which bit of your code is actually slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you call `getList` again and again and again. Instead, call it once and store the result in a list:

```
all_the_dates = getList()
userInp = raw_input("Enter a date: ")
for i in range(0,len(all_the_dates)):
    if (all_the_dates[i][0]) == userInp:
        print userInp + " falls on " + all_the_dates[i][1] + "."
```

Or shorter, iterating the list directly instead of using a `range` of indices:

```
for date, weekday in all_the_dates:
    if date == userInp:
        print userInp + " falls on " + weekday + "."
```

Having said that, you do not need that "calendar" file at all. Just use Python's [`datetime.date`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) API and [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to get the weekday.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> userinp = "2/1/2018"
>>> m,d,y = map(int, userinp.split("/"))
>>> datetime.date(y, m, d).strftime("%A")
'Thursday'
```

Comment: Sweet. Makes much sense. Thank you!